# Deeplearning with electroencephalography (EEG) data

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I am making a convolutional network model with which I want to classify EEG data. The data is an experiment where participants are evoked with images of 3 different classes with 2 subclasses each. To give a brief explanation about the dataset size, a subclass has ±300 epochs of a given participant (this applies for all the subclasses).

1. Object
2. Color
3. Number

I have 5 participants in my training dataset, I took 15% of each participants' data and put it in the testing dataset. Can I consider the 15% as unseen data even though the same participant was used to train the model on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to test. A test set is used to estimate the generalization (i.e. performance on unseen data). So the question is:

- Do want to estimate the generalization to unseen data from the same participants (whose data was used to train the classifier)?
- Or do you want to estimate the generalization to unseen participants (the general population)?

This really depends on you goal or the claim you are trying to make. I can think of situations for both approaches:

- Think of BCIs which need to be retrained for every user. Here, you would test on data from the same individual.
- On the other hand, if you make a very general claim (e.g. I can decode some relevant signal from a certain brain region across the population) then having a test set consisting of participants which were not included in the training set would lend much stronger support to your claim. (The question is whether this works, though.)

Comment: The classifier at the moment classifies 95% accurate on excluded testing data from participants who were trained on. But when I try to classify on a participant who was excluded from training, the classification is random. It is more an experimental study, to see what is possible when using CNN with EEG data.